# SSIS BCP & Flat File - Is there a limit to how many records can be in the file?

Tags: ssis

The file I am working with has about 207 million rows. In SSIS it keeps failing.

> The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 2. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.

Now when I copy a chunk of rows and place into another txt and import I don't get the error.

I can get the rows into sql if I don't use Bulk Insert and use a regular data flow task.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should check:

1. Column length definition for column `2`. It's probably set to something like `100` and you try to import a row having a column with a length higher than that.
2. Check, if you got a column delimiter that may occur inside the data. Imaging you got a file with `;` as delimiter, the flat file will run into problem when you got a value containing a semicolon.

The file is pretty long, but i don't think it has something to do with it because the error would be something else.

Comment: I successfully used BCP on a smaller version of the big file....but when I try the big file I get the error.

Comment: Consider the following situation: By creating and configuration a new task to import a flat file, the flat file will guess the length of the output column for every import column. To guess, it uses the first ~100 rows. So if there are 100 column values with a length of 10 and the values 101 got a length of 20, you task will fail. This might be an error inside the file like a missing delimiter, or the values are variing that much.

Answer (score 0):

One other thing you can do is make sure bulk insert is turned off on the oledb destination.  On rare occasions I'll get records that don't insert with it turned on.

In fact, if someone knows why that is, I'd love to know.